# Windows built in photo editor

Tags: windows-10

How do I find this photo editor in my Windows 10 machine?
[https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/make-a-picture-transparent-ce96ac80-5afc-436c-ae3f-0c78009bf704#:~:text=Double%2Dclick%20the%20picture%2C%20and,you%20want%20to%20make%20transparent](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/make-a-picture-transparent-ce96ac80-5afc-436c-ae3f-0c78009bf704#:%7E:text=Double%2Dclick%20the%20picture%2C%20and,you%20want%20to%20make%20transparent).

Looks like this to make photos transparent:
[image]

Comment: Right at the top of the page - "This feature is available only in Office 2021 and to Microsoft 365 Subscribers for Windows desktop clients."

Comment: How do I find out if I have that version?

Comment: Did you buy it? If not, then you don't.

Comment: no its a computer that came with my employeer

Comment: Then they're most likely to know if they bought it or not. We don't know.

Comment: The article is for Office 2021. Do you have Office 2021 installed. The editor is NOT the built-in photo editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your link doesn't describe a built-in photo editor.
It describes ways for displaying an image that was embedded in an
Office document, for example by Word.

The closest Windows 10/11 equivalent to a photo-editor is the Photos
application. Enter `Photos` in the Start menu to see if you have
this application.

If you don't have Photos, or it's too limited for your purpose,
a free and good photo-editor I recommend is
[Paint.NET](https://www.getpaint.net/).